# Xamarin iOS buttons not working

Tags: ios, xamarin

I've implemented a Xamarin cross platform application. However, all the buttons is working fine in Android, but most of them are not working in iOS. How come?

```
<Button x:Name="MyButton" 
        Text="1" 
        Clicked="On1Clicked" />
```

I thought that the whole idea with Cross platform was that it should be multi supportive, especially these basic controls.

Comment: Can you share with us a little more of your XAML code? Maybe there's some issue with parent element of buttons.

Comment: @Vahid I realized that the problem only concerns those buttons that are inside a customized control. But again, it's working for Android.

Comment: @random Without seeing your XAML, I would **assume** if you can "see" the button but can not click on the button, then there is a transparent element on top those buttons....?

Comment: @SushiHangover Yes, you're right. I solved it a couple of minutes ago. It proved that there was another control on top of it.